# Как убрать фильтр на wp_head добавленный AMP плагином?

Tags: wordpress, amp

плагин амп добавлет 
как убрать хук, который добавляет этот код на wp_head
плагин AMP for WP – Accelerated Mobile Pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы про этот плагин https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/accelerated-mobile-pages/ то:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'amp_frontend_add_canonical' );
```

Comment: не работает. при добавлении как в functions.php так и перед вызовом самой функции wp_head()